# Django: Use external function with django variables

Tags: python, django, variables, import

Hi I'm new in Django and Python and I have a very big trouble:
I would perform a Django app that allow me to input two numbers and to use an external function (a very simple python file) to do any mathematical operation (it does not matter what). I hope to be clear in making the question:

*How can I call my two numbers in my external function and then import the obtained result in my Django app?*

I explain with some code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ElementiTab(models.Model):
    des = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    res = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

(For the moment I insert 'des', 'x', 'y' from shell)

forms.py

```
from django import forms               
from .models import ElementiTab

class  ElementiTabForm(forms.ModelForm):        

    class Meta:                        
        model =  ElementiTab
        fields = ('des', 'x', 'y','res' )
```

where 'des' is a simple description

'x' and 'y' are my two numbers

'res'is the result of my external function

views.py (html is not a truble)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ElementiTab

def tabval(request):
    valori = ElementiTab.objects.filter()
    return render(request, 'apptabella/tabval.html', {'valori': valori})
```

my external function that, in IDLE Python, works:

oper.py

```
a = float(input('a =  '))
b = float(input('b =  '))

operation = (a+b)/b

print (operation)
```

Pratically I would sobstitute 'a' and 'b' with  'x' and 'y' variables of models.py and I am only interested on execute 'operation' and to put the result in 'res' variable.

At the end I have shows my app (a table) on browser similar to this:

|DES|  X  |  Y  |RES|

|bla      |1.3  | 0.4| 0.0   |

|asd     |2.0|1.3| 0.0  |

etc--

RES is the column where I want to show 'res' (now zero, of course)
I have put oper.py in the Django app folder. I tried to import variables and so on but with no success! I have no ideas!

A big "thank you" to those who can help me!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here. Django is just Python, you can import any external module and call its functions.

Comment: I know this; but the problem (for me) is HOW to import and then USE any external module. I am new.. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: But you're using import fine in your code when you're importing Django modules. Why is it different importing your own?

Comment: If I try to import oper.py in models.py, I occur in 'unsolved import' error, the same if I try, in oper.py, to import x and y form models.py and set a = x and b = y.
So my trouble is how to "connect"  'x', 'y' with 'a','b' and 'operation' with 'res'.
I have to define 'res', 'a', 'b' in a different way? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Daniel in the comments, you can import any other python file. Two things for you to consider:

1) Are you trying to import oper.py as "import oper.py" or "import oper"? It needs to be the latter.

2) You probably want to define a function in oper.py, for example, this slight modification of what you wrote above:

```
def add_divide(a, b):
    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    operation = (a+b)/b
    return operation
```

Then you can call it from your views.py like so:

```
import oper
oper.add_divide(5,10)
```

If you're getting hung up on importing from another file, then try just adding your function above tabval in views.py

Update - I'm uncertain if your goal is to actually try reading an external file, yet if x and y are from the form, you would usually do something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class ElementiTab(models.Model):
    des = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    res = models.FloatField(default=0)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.res = (float(self.x)+float(self.y))/float(self.y)
        super(ElementiTab, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

More details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

UPDATE:
An example that ties everything together can be found here: https://github.com/kelvinn/externaloperexample

In particular, look at the models.py file:
https://github.com/kelvinn/externaloperexample/blob/master/apptabella/models.py

And how it calls/uses the 'add_divide' function on lines 2 and 11.

Comment: ok for the import, of course! but I would  put 'x' and 'y'  values previously saved in DB instead of (5, 10) and I would tell to my DB that res = model.FloatField is 'operation'!

Comment: ok rightly I have to save the result of the operation, thanks for the link!
My goal is to do some "operations" from an external file! You image a very complicated function that I can't define in models.py because it is too long and complex to write it there! in this question I used a simple function only for example.
On Django documents I have not found any examples about my trouble.
Sorry I'm very new but I need to understand this point if possible.

Comment: Hi Beatrix - I took some time to write up an example of using an external file, tying together everything we've talked about above. If this helps you, then please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: you solved a very difficult trouble for a 'newbie' like me. Now I study your precious code :) I can't put +1 to your answer because I have only 1 in reputation!

Comment: No worries - we've all had to start somewhere! Good luck with your adventure.

Comment: Can you explain me where You have set the name of the forms? I would change e.g. 'Des:' of the 1st form and I would change 'This field is required' when I submit without input

Comment: The names of the form are being derived directly from the fields in forms.py, because the form is being generated from your model - you can either manually create the form (with labels) in HTML, or specify each field manually and add a label to each field. Take a look at the first example here: http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/forms.html